# iPhone generic string, text, choice editor controller

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitextview, uipickerview

Each time I build an iphone application, I found myself writing the same code over and over again: generic *string || text || choice* editor controllers.

Imagine a tableview showing some data that I want to edit. When I click a string field (short text), I open a generic string editor controller, with a tableview with 1 cell, and a keyboard. After the user saves or cancels the controller, a delegate function is called on the parent window.

I write the same code for editing text (big strings) and selecting from a list of choices.

**Question**: am I missing something for the SDK that does this already? Is there some kind of opensource library that already implements this in a consistent and easy way?